# How do I add an overlay to my OpenStreetMap

Tags: php, google-maps, tiles, openstreetmap

I currently use a google map and create tiles for it by using a PHP script to generate the required PNG images

```
 var myTileLayer = new GTileLayerOverlay(
                                new GTileLayer(null, null, null, {
                                    //tileUrlTemplate: 'Overlays/Overlay_{Z}_{X}_{Y}.png',
                                    tileUrlTemplate: 'gentile.php?Zoom={Z}&TileX={X}&TileY={Y}',
                                    isPng:true,
                                    opacity:1.0
                                })
                            );

                                map.addOverlay(myTileLayer);
```

I now wish to use OpenStreetMap and according to this source: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example

I need to use this code to acheive that, however it seems to want me to use premade tiles when I want to gen them on the fly

```
 var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("New Layer", "URL_TO_TILES/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19});
 map.addLayer(newLayer);
```

Really I need to use gentile.php?Zoom={Z}&TileX={X}&TileY={Y}

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to use OpenStreetMap with OpenLayers? Or with the google maps API? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you whant to use OpenLayers to show your own Overlay on an OSM(or what ever)-map?

And you hav to use and your tiles lays at an URL like "gentile.php?Zoom={Z}&TileX={X}&TileY={Y}"

So try to add the layer with:

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("New Layer", "gentile.php?Zoom=${Z}&TileX=${X}&TileY=${Y}", {numZoomLevels: 19});
```

i've used that an year ago...

if that doesn't work write an htaccess - [mod_rewrite](http://www.modrewrite.de)

eg something like that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).png$ gentile.php?Zoom=$1&TileX=$2&TileY=$3 [NC]
```